# How to select listbox valuemember at random?

Tags: database, vb.net, random, listbox

I have a listbox filled with a datasource, the datasource is an access database with a numeric primary key. The primary key is set to be the valuemember of the listbox. I want to click a button and have one of the items in the listbox selected at random.

I have been trying:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim rnd As New Random

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'Fills listbox, adds Valuemember and Displaymember
     Me.Recipe_tableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Recipes2DataSet.recipe_table)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim randomIndex1 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, ListBox1.Items.Count)
    ListBox1.SelectedValue = randomIndex1
End Sub
```

This kind of works, but I get a unique value exception because it looks like the selection is trying to add to the database. I just want to select one item at random.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's a better idea to change the index of the listbox instead of the value itself. By changing the `SelectedIndex` instead of the `SelectedValue`, nothing happens to the actual values of the listbox. Try this:

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = rnd.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count)
```

Just remember that indices are zero-based, so that's why the specified lower bound in the `Random.Next` method is a zero.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am still getting an exception:System.Data.ContraintException {"Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique.  Value '14' is already present."} ID is the primary key in my database with numeric values 1..21

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you posted. Modifying the selection should not do anything with the data itself, so something is missing. Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: I have the Selected Value of the listbox equal to the primary key of the database. If I change it to another column, when an item is selected in the listbox either by the random button or by click, I notice numbers show up as items in the listbox. When it is set to the primary key, I get the exception.